# how do i fire textFieldDidEndEditing function for a textfield created programmatically

Tags: ios5, uitextfield, keyboard-events

The following is the code that i am writing

```
UITextField *category =[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 90, subView.frame.size.width-15, 30)];
category.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
category.placeholder = @"Category, Description, Model (optional)";
category.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
// [category addTarget:self action:@selector(textFeild) forControlEvents:<#(UIControlEvents)#>]
```

What should the statement be so that I can add the textFieldDidEndEditing control event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the delegate of `UITextField` to self

```
category.delegate = self;
```

Make sure your class which creates the `UITextField` implements the `UITextFieldDelegate`

Comment: Doesnt work, I am not what is wrong. This doesnot even fire the keyboard will hide notification

Comment: try changing the returnkeytype to Done or return or default